# Keep rows in a multidimensional array which contain a specific substring

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, filtering, array-filter

I have the follow API output, I basicly want to grab the member ids when the field relative contains 'minutes'  how can I do this with an array filter?

```
[
    'members' => [ 
        239 => ['relative' => '21 minutes ago'],
        941591 => ['relative' => '5 hours ago'],        
        4178 => ['relative' => '59 minutes ago'],       
        78 => ['relative' => '2 hours ago']
    ]
]
```

(not sure on the correct terms) but "relative" is a header/field name below the member ids,  and the field relative contains the values like: "59 minutes ago"

I know I can get my answer by looping through all members and checking the field, but I prefer not to do it this way

Comment: Use `array_filter()`? The name is right there in your title and tags.

Comment: Use `array_keys()` to get the member IDs after filtering.

Comment: I'm sorry i am aware that array_filter() is a function. i mainly don't how to use it in this case.
 (mainly to check if it contains 'minutes')  array_filter($array, $functiontocheckforminutes)

Comment: is this multi-line text or is this a multi-dimensional array in some notation?

Comment: I would like this question reopend, it was closed for not focussing on 1 issue. but this is simply incorrect. I might not have formulated it perfectly (because i dont know the terms for most things) But this is 1 issue/question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the `relative` column and grep for ones that contain `minutes`:

```
$result = preg_grep('/minutes/', array_column($array['members'], 'relative'));
```

Or filter:

```
$result = array_filter($array['members'],
                       function($v) {
                           return strpos($v['relative'], 'minutes') !== false;
                       });
```

Then just get the keys:

```
$ids = array_keys($result);
```

Comment: Thank you, 
Is either one of those faster then the other by any chance?

Comment: It doesnt seem to work, Not sure how to explain it properly, but i believe the reason is because "relative" isn't an output but a header/key/not sure what its callled
but its
members
-> an id for each member
-> data field relative
-> That contains the part: 59 minutes ago

Comment: Got it to work due to this, i used the filter:
$new = array_filter($idcall_array['members'], function ($var) {
    return strpos($var['relative'], 'minutes') !== false;
});

Comment: Edited both, thanks!